# Python class for handling custom file type

Tags: python, file

### Background

I am devising a simple file format to store some (possibly large) binary data together with some metadata that specifies how the data was generated:

```
<HEADER | 4 bytes> (specifies 'size' of METADATA)
<METADATA | 'size' bytes>
<DATA>
```

The use case is that if at some later point I just want to inspect the metadata (i.e. without touching the actual data), then I won't read the entire structure, but only the `<METADATA>` part (of known size).

I implemented the following class to facilitate working with such files. It behaves similarly to a singleton, loads metadata or data when first requested, then holds the reference to them during the entire lifespan of the class.

I am planning to use [`hypothesis`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for testing (generating random data of various types).

### Code

```py
import numpy as np
import pickle
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any, Union


class MyFile:

    HEADER_SIZE_BYTES = 4

    def __init__(self, filename: Union[str, Path]):
        self.filename = filename

        self.__metadata = None
        self.__data = None
        
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
            self.metadata_size = int.from_bytes(fp.read(self.HEADER_SIZE_BYTES), "little")

    def get_metadata(self) -> Any:
        if self.__metadata is None:
            with open(self.filename, "rb") as fp:
                fp.seek(self.HEADER_SIZE_BYTES, 1)
                self.__metadata = pickle.loads(fp.read(self.metadata_size))

        return self.__metadata

    def set_metadata(self, metadata: Any) -> None:
        self.__metadata = metadata

    def get_data(self) -> Any:
        if self.__data is None:
            with open(self.filename, "rb") as fp:
                fp.seek(self.HEADER_SIZE_BYTES + self.metadata_size, 1)
                self.__data = pickle.loads(fp.read())

        return self.__data
    
    def set_data(self, data: Any) -> None:
        self.__data = data

    def write_all(self) -> None:
        if self.__metadata is None:
            raise ValueError("No metadata to write!")

        if self.__data is None:
            raise ValueError("No data to write!")

        metadata_bytes = pickle.dumps(self.__metadata)
        data_bytes = pickle.dumps(self.__data)
        header_bytes = len(metadata_bytes).to_bytes(self.HEADER_SIZE_BYTES, "little")

        with open(self.filename, 'wb') as fp:
            fp.write(header_bytes)
            fp.write(metadata_bytes)
            fp.write(data_bytes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = MyFile("out.epkl")
    
    meta_w = {
        "foo": "bar",
        "baz": [1, 2, 3],
    }
    data_w = np.random.rand(3, 10, 10)

    f.set_metadata(meta_w)
    f.set_data(data_w)
    f.write_all()

    g = MyFile("out.epkl")
    
    meta_r = g.get_metadata()
    data_r = g.get_data()
    
    assert meta_r == meta_w
    assert np.allclose(data_r, data_w)
```

### Comments

What are the crucial aspects that you, as a user of this library, would require from it?

I feel like things can be improved: there's some duplicated code, and possibly some edge-cases that I did not consider.

Comment: I updated the code with the possibility to write to files. I am thinking that maybe I can specify the opening mode: `r`, `w`, `rw`, or even append, and have some sort of "standard" interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It's not necessary to represent this as a class; a read and write function will suffice
- Don't use double-underscores; that's reserved for name mangling
- The second argument of `Union[str, Path]` is more generically expressed as `os.PathLike`
- Pickled objects are already length-aware. The much easier approach than what you've shown here is to omit any manual length information, and simply do two sequential serialization calls to pickle.
- Particularly since you're using pickle and not e.g. JSON, there is no excuse to have poorly-typed data. Replace your dictionary with `dataclass` or similar.

The following suggested code represents the write operation as a naive method assuming both metadata and body are already in memory; and read as an iterator that yields them one at a time. Drop the logging if you don't need it; it's more to demonstrate successful operation than anything else.

```
import logging
import pickle
from dataclasses import dataclass
from os import PathLike
from sys import stdout
from typing import Iterable, Union, List


import numpy as np

logger = logging.getLogger('pickling_experments')


@dataclass
class Metadata:
    foo: str
    baz: List[int]


def write_pickle(
    metadata: Metadata, 
    body: np.ndarray,
    path: Union[str, PathLike] = 'out.epkl',
) -> None:
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(metadata, f)
        logger.debug(f'Position after metadata: {f.tell()}')
        pickle.dump(body, f)
        logger.debug(f'Position after {body.nbytes}-byte body: {f.tell()}')


def read_pickle(
    path: Union[str, PathLike] = 'out.epkl',
    get_metadata: bool = True,
    get_body: bool = True,
) -> Iterable[
    Union[Metadata, np.ndarray]
]:
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        metadata = pickle.load(f)
        logger.debug(f'Position after metadata: {f.tell()}')
        if get_metadata:
            yield metadata

        if not get_body:
            return
        body = pickle.load(f)
        logger.debug(f'Position after {body.nbytes}-byte body: {f.tell()}')

    yield body


def test():
    logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stdout))
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    print('Write:')
    write_pickle(
        Metadata(foo='bar', baz=[1, 2, 3]), 
        np.random.random((512, 512)),
    )

    print('\nCombined read:', flush=True)
    metadata, body = read_pickle()

    print('\nSeparated read:', flush=True)
    results = read_pickle()
    metadata = next(results)
    print('Twiddle your thumbs for a while here; large memory not yet consumed', flush=True)
    body = next(results)

    print('\nMetadata-only read:', flush=True)
    metadata, = read_pickle(get_body=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Output:

```
Write:
Position after metadata: 68
Position after 2097152-byte body: 2097383

Combined read:
Position after metadata: 68
Position after 2097152-byte body: 2097383

Separated read:
Position after metadata: 68
Twiddle your thumbs for a while here; large memory not yet consumed
Position after 2097152-byte body: 2097383

Metadata-only read:
Position after metadata: 68
```

Comment: Thank you, very clear and comprehensive! "Pickled objects are already length-aware." - today I learned! This is extremely neat, since now different pickled objects can simply be concatenated; the file pointer is advanced "for free".

Comment: In general I discourage people from pickling any custom classes for long-term storage. While this might work with your particular code *right now*, you will possibly struggle to load files saved with your library a few versions ago. E.g. if you save them as object of type `Metadata`, you won't be able to load them if you rename the class to `MetaData`. Or even worse, pickle with `mypackage.utils.Metadata` and then do some refactoring - suddenly you'll find out that you're unable to unpickle it just because class has been moved to `mypackage.types.Metadata`!

Comment: @BIOStheZerg responsible versioning and strong types are not mutually exclusive. Sit on that one for a minute. A responsible versioning system is not one that "allows anything" in serialization, but rather, has well-defined types for every version that has been published.

Comment: But that ("for every version") is the problem, not the solution. One should have data storage independent of the code, and a new version of the code should just have an updated readers/writers with as much backward (and forward!) compatibility as practical. But let's not get into a discussion in here :)